# how to browse and open a file on window dialog box using vb scripting

Tags: vb.net, dialog, window

For one of the requirement, I need to click on browse button on the UI which will open up the window dialog box with title "Choose File to Upload". I need to input file name in the input box for file name and click on Open button on this window dialog.
I tried the code to activate this window and to use shell script to send keys, but it's not working. Can someone please help in getting this resolved?[snapshot of the window dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Zm4.jpg)

```
Do 
  bResult = objWshShell.AppActivate("Choose File to Upload")
  If bResult = True Then 
    oShell.SendKeys "C:\text.xls"
    oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Exit Do 
  End If 
  WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

`Do 
     bResult = objWshShell.AppActivate("Choose File to Upload")
     If bResult = True Then 
     oShell.SendKeys "%n"
     oShell.SendKeys "C:\text.xls"
     oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
     Exit Do 
     End If 
     WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".